# Shouldn't questions be numbered (given an unique id)?

Tags: feature-request

With a unique id for a question one can call attention to the previous questions with ease and also hyper text it.

Answer (score 2):

They are. For example, your meta question right here is #494: `meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/494`

Here's biology.SE #1: `biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1`

Comment: Where is the question number shown? It is not visible to me.

Comment: Look at the url of questions. The format is: *biology.stackexchange.com/questions/"Question_number"/"Title"*

Comment: SE autoconverted my links. It's the number after `biology.stackexchange.com/questions/`

Comment: You can also shorten the URLs to things like `http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/1` to save space.

Comment: Answers also have their own unique IDs: `http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/59`

Comment: "Last thing a deep sea fish will discover is salt water" The simple answer should have been look at the URL as suggested by fileunderwater. Things need not be obvious for those who seek the answer.

Comment: You can click share under the post. The last number is your user ID and can be omitted if you like.